# Getting a "missing } inserted" error

Tags: errors

I'm a LaTeX newbie so pardon my ignorance. I'm getting a "missing } inserted" one the last line of this code. Any help greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

%\usepackage{doublespace}
%\setstretch{1.2}

\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{CV}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{.75in}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-.75in}

 \setlength\parindent{0pt}


\begin{document}



\pagestyle{empty}

%Ueberschrift
\begin{center}
\huge{\textsc{Robert Elder}}\\
\small{\textsc{Assistant Professor of History}
\vspace{\baselineskip}



\small{\textsc{Tabor College \\ 400 S. Jefferson St. \\ Hillsboro, KS 67063 \\ Phone   (office): 620-947-3121 ext. 1064 \\ Phone (cell): 864-506-6830 \\ roberte@tabor.edu}}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Haven't tested, but a quick look suggests a missing `}` at the end of this line: `\small{\textsc{Assistant Professor of History}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

```
\small{\textsc{Assistant Professor of History}
```

is the source of error. But `\small`, `\huge` etc. are switches, so using them with arguments is not correct. Hence rather

```
{\small\textsc{Assistant Professor of History}}
```